SQL Server Backup Best Practices
Our database admin left and since I'm the only other person who knows SQL I've been taking over those duties, but I'm still learning.
We have a server with several SQL Server databases.
I have them set for full recovery to minimize data loss.
Over the weekend I discovered that one of the databases had a log file that ballooned out of control and eventually filled the disk, and the transaction log file backups had also filled the backup drive, which thankfully I found before it could cause many issues.
I did a shrinkfile on the database log, and removed a lot of older transaction log backups, so things are ok for the moment.
I am trying to figure out the best strategy for retaining backups, and since this is an area that I'm new to I would love a sanity check.
We currently have a weekly full backup every Sunday night, a daily differential backup the other nights, and to make sure that stuff isn't lost during the day transaction log backups every 15 minutes.
The weekly full backups also get moved off site so that we don't have a single point of failure.
My thinking is in order to save space that once a full backup happens on Sunday the differential and transaction log backups aren't really needed any more, and so maybe they could just be purged, and then I would just keep several months worth of weekly backups for just in case reasons.
Or would that be a bad idea?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I do want point in time, but it probably only needs to go back a few days, maybe a week at most. It's mostly insurance in case a typo causes something stupid to happen, like 'oh crap I pushed the wrong button and updated all the rows to change the name to bill'. Then I can just restore the table to a temp db and update the rows with the correct data. Anything before last week is less "someone made a booboo" and more "the server is on fire and we have to start over".

Let me sum up.
Your backup strategy: weekly full, daily diff and log backup every 15 minutes looks reasonable, however (based on your questions) I see lack of communications from you and business owner.
It's not random person from the internet should suggest you to drop or keep backups, it should be the person who pays bills (your salary, SQL server license, and storage expenses) to answer this question.
Those folks don't care about your backups, they need ABILITY TO RECOVER. They have to define how far backup they need to recover and ask you questions

how long does it take (and what are the options to do it faster)
if you have a failure what is your plan B (or what is your redundancy level)
are you sure you can do it? (how do you test your plans)
what if you are on vacation or sick, who else can do it (how it is
documented)

As new guy feel free to setup a meeting with them and clear out:

what can you do for them
what they expect you to do

If you all on the same page - great. If they are not happy (I want it all I want it now) there are options and price.
Here are my suggestions.
With every 15 minutes to backup there are a lots of files (up to 24 * 4 * 7=672) and it's hard and error prone to put it manually so I'd recommend to use sp_DatabaseRestore
I hope you run backups not on the local server but on network share
so you can set up a server with only purpose to test restore databases from this share so if it failed you have time to fix it.
As bonus you can run CHECKDB after restore. Also you have preallocated space for your databases. You can even use it for queries but beware: if you read it you have to license it.
What about other pieces of equation like logins, passwords for SQL Server logins, server roles for logins, certificates, SQL agent jobs, SSIS packages, linked servers, etc ?
It stored in system databases but restore of those databases is not practiced too often so you can script it on the regular basis.
